# Use case diagram hierarchy and associations

Tags: uml, use-case

I've been studying use case diagrams for a little while now and i've created my own to model one for a mobile banking system. However, in my model there is one thing that i am unsure how to accomplish. In the picture below, you can see the user. I dragged arrows to the subusers(pincode user, secure key device user, e-legitimation user). By this solution I am not sure if the subusers will get access to the login circle or not, because they don't have any arrows going to it.

So I guess my question is: Will the subusers(pincode user, secure key device user, e-legitimation user) be able to log in with this diagram or not?

Also will the current diagram force the subusers to login or are they just able to pass the login? Is an include arrow needed somewhere here perhaps?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your diagram your subusers can use login usecase but this login usecase is not required by any other usecases.
For modeling the fact taht a usecase A "needs" another usecase B you have to create an include from B to A.

RB

Just a little remark: the display of yours include and generalization links look wrong for me which is ironic when using a graphical language :-D

Comment: Are you sure about all of the user-cases? I think "Check account balance" requires the login user-case. Should i draw a line and include the transfer user-case to the login use-case to make it required?

Comment: if "Check Account balance" requires "login" a include from "CAB" to "login" would ehlp the comprehension